# Add an Image Upload button to the Mobile Site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mobile-web, images, editor

With the release of iOS 6, the most commonly used mobile browser now supports standard generic image upload buttons. This is actually really handy.  I can take screenshots on my phone or iPad, and use them to answer questions about apps made to run on those devices (or [take advantage of resources specific to those devices](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91990/is-there-anything-near-the-rune-in-the-water-at-lady-boyles-last-party/92000#92000)) to answer questions. Until the release of iOS 6 however, the only way to use these images in my answer was to either sync them over to my computer, and then answer from a desktop, or use a specialized app to upload the images, such as PicUp or DropBox, and then manually write out the markdown code.

After iOS 6, the Image Upload button works just fine, **if** I switch to viewing the full site from my iDevice, rather than the mobile view. I can upload images directly, and the markdown is handled for me. It's awesome, except for the fact that the non-mobile site is decidedly non-awesome on the small screen of my phone.

Which brings me to my feature request: Add the Image Upload button (and other markdown shortcuts, as deemed worthwhile) to the ask/answer editors on the mobile version of SE sites.

Comment: This would be extremely useful.

Comment: It would be interesting to see some statistics of how many answers are being posted from the mobile version.

Comment: @Lix I'd wager that number is being suppressed by the severe limitations of the mobile site. Anything that requires formatting or more than a sentence or two can be a pain in the rear.

Comment: Is that a limitation of the site, or the device, @LessPop_MoreFizz? What do you find lacking?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Up until a few weeks ago, it was a limitation of the device. There was no way to do it. Now, the device is no longer limited, and I'd like to see the site provide a button to take advantage of that fact. The alternative is to not use the mobile site (which *does* work, but is very unpleasant.)

Comment: Yeah, I see that in your request, but your comment above seemed to imply more problems than just lack of image upload.

Comment: Looks like android has had this [since 2.2 at least](http://blog.flickr.net/en/2010/09/23/new-browser-based-uploads-on-android-2-2/) so that's extra reason to impliment it. That and iOS 6 should cover a majority of (active) smartphones

Comment: This would also be really useful in the mobile chat sites.

Answer (score 3):

This is implemented now. Note that the file upload size limit (currently 2 MB) still applies, and that some phones don't upload a smaller image if you take a picture with your camera - highly frustrating :(

Screenshots shouldn't cause any issues, haven't encountered truly huge ones that break that limit.

Comment: Should I post a separate feature request for mobile chat?