# How to post images on a mobile device

Tags: support, mobile-web, images

So I was writing a post on my mobile device, and I needed to post an image. Is there way to do that (I am using an iPhone)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of iOS 6, you can switch over to the full version of the site and use the usual image upload button in the editor. You can also upload  the image through some alternate application and write out the image Markdown manually (`![alt](url)`), but this is tedious and not preferred (as the image won't be reliably hosted on Stack Exchange's imgur).

Dealing with the full version of the site on an iPhone can be a bit of a pain, though, so you should throw an up vote in the direction of [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153551/add-an-image-upload-button-to-the-mobile-site) that asks for an image upload button to be added to the mobile view.

Comment: I've tried using the desktop site on my phone to add an image but the File input button doesn't seem to be clickable or potentially the click area is so small that I was incapable of registering a click to trigger it.