# Page goes back to top when dismissing Add picture dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, mobile-safari

The [new Add picture dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153551/245360) on the mobile website (on mobile Safari) goes back to the top of the page when dismissing it.

This is really distracting when you want to post an answer and you suddenly lose the edit box.

Can we preserve focus on the edit box when dismissing the dialog please?

Comment: Same on mobile Chrome (iOS) too.

Comment: Fixed, had it for when you submit but not when you cancel.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind adding an answer?

Comment: @MichaelStum can you post an answer to make it more... official? Thanks!